# Change a value in a PHP variable using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a value in a php variable `$thumb_path="images/Gallery1/thumbs/";`. I need to change this value to `$thumb_path="images/Gallery2/thumbs/";` when I am clicking on Gallery2 Link n my project. Is it possible to change a value in a PHP variable using JavaScript?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i do not think you are approaching your problem correctly. php is happening on the server side, however javascript is client-side (browser). perhaps if you provide background for your problem we can help direct you to the correct course of action

Answer (score 2):

JS is a client side language, PHP is parsed on server, so you can't change the php file itself with js... BUT: :)

You can manage it with GET:

```
$thumb_path="images/Gallery".(($_GET['gallery'] && preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $_GET['gallery'])) ? $_GET['gallery'] : "1")."/thumbs/";
```

now you can call your link like this:

```
http://www.page.com/yourphpfile.php?gallery=2
```

This will open gallery 2.

If you dont set ?gallery gallery 1 will shown as default.

Comment: you should check the GET var because of possible malicous code... for example do an intval() on it...

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is a client-, and PHP is a server-side language, obviously you can't.

You can use some AJAX if possible. If this is some kind of dynamic variable (you'll getting this data from a form), you can change it with JavaScript.

Comment: http://funnyjoke.wordpress.com/2006/12/16/technically-correct-but-a-completely-useless-answer/